# Find all year in specific portion of text file

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all years from specific portion of text file through search pattern but I couldn't do to start search from the line I first found.

Here is what I got.

```
for line in infile_1:
    if '[edit]Crime' in line:
    print(re.findall(r'\d{4}',line[1:]))
    for i in infile_1:
        if '[edit]Education' in infile:
              break
```

This get only empty bracket. It is wrong.

Text:

```
[edit]Crime
Main articles: Crime in Chicago and Organized crime in Chicago
Murders in the city peaked first in 1974, with 970 murders when the city's population was over 3 million people (resulting in a murder rate of around 29 per 100,000), and again in 1992 with 943 murders, resulting in a murder rate of 34 per 100,000.[114] Chicago, along with other major US cities, experienced a significant reduction in violent crime rates through the 1990s, eventually recording 448 homicides in 2004, the lowest total since 1965 (15.65 per 100,000.) Chicago's homicide tally remained steady throughout 2005, 2006, and 2007 with 449, 452, and 435 respectively.

In 2008, murders rebounded to 510, 2nd highest in the country (though not in per capita rate), breaking 500 for the first time since 2003.[115][116] For 2009 the murder count was down about 10% for the year, to 458.[117]

2010 saw Chicago's murder rate at its lowest levels since 1965. Overall, 435 homicides were recorded for the year, a 5% decrease from 2009.[118]
```

Comment: provide some sample data from `infile_1`

Comment: post your portion of text file

Comment: I edit it below the code section.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: All year in specific portion. I should report [1974] and stop reporting if it reach the [edit] Education

Comment: can you do `print(line)` and find out what it prints?

Comment: It prints just [edit]Crime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `[edit]Education` part by splitting the text, and then check `[edit]Crime` section:

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('[edit]Crime')[1].split('[edit]')[0]
years = re.findall('(\d\d\d\d)', data)
```

Output:

```
['1974']
```

Comment: I'm sorry I for get to tell this 1 section only, There is more before crime. Is there anyway to search through until it found crime section and start searching.

Comment: So you need to skip everything before and after Crime section?

Comment: Exactly yes, Just report year in Crime section.

Comment: Does Crime section is only one-line paragraph? Or it can contains several paragraphs starting with new line?

Comment: You read the whole text, then you remove the part before Crime section, then you remove part after Crime section. And then you regex in Crime section.

Comment: That's a legit approach. I've trying to search until I found crime section then begin to do regex and break it off until I found another section. But, I couldn't figure it out after it found the Crime section.  Thank You!